# Ruby join a hash and a list +remaining values

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, hash

I want to join a hash on its keys and a list
Example:

```
a={"aa"=>[1, 2], "bbb"=>[3, 4, 5], "c"=>[6, 7, 8], "hh"=>[9]}
b=["aa","c"]
```

(the elements of b list will ALWAYS present in a hash)

I want to join a list with a hash and preserve the values of a hash. So I need to get the following:

```
c={"aa"=>[1,2],"c"=>[6,7,8]}
```

What is the fastest way to do it? My a hash can include up to 110.000 keys.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = {"aa"=>[1, 2], "bbb"=>[3, 4, 5], "c"=>[6, 7, 8], "hh"=>[9]} 
b = ["aa", "c"] 
a.select{|k,v| b.include? k}
#=> {"aa"=>[1, 2], "c"=>[6, 7, 8]}
```

You should consider using a set, since it is semantically correct and will perform way better than the linear search from `Array#include?`.

```
require 'set'
a = {"aa"=>[1, 2], "bbb"=>[3, 4, 5], "c"=>[6, 7, 8], "hh"=>[9]} 
b = Set.new ["aa", "c"] 
a.select{|k,v| b.include? k}
#=> {"aa"=>[1, 2], "c"=>[6, 7, 8]}
```

Comment: Note that [the "each" solution from @steenslag](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16737714/244128) is likely faster.

Answer (score 3):

```ruby
c = b.reduce({}) { |memo,x| memo[x]=a[x]; memo }
# => {"aa"=>[1, 2], "c"=>[6, 7, 8]}
```

**[Edit]** Just for kicks, here is a benchmark of a few strategies here: "reduce", "each", and "set":

```ruby
require 'benchmark'
require 'set'
a = {"aa"=>[1, 2], "bbb"=>[3, 4, 5], "c"=>[6, 7, 8], "hh"=>[9]} 
b = ["aa", "c"]
n = 1_000
Benchmark.bm(8) do |x|
  x.report("reduce:") { n.times { b.reduce({}) { |memo,x| memo[x]=a[x]; memo } } }
  x.report("each:") { n.times { c={}; b.each{|key| c[key] = a[key]} } }
  x.report("set:") { n.times { bset=Set.new ['aa','c']; a.select{|k,v| bset.include? k} } }
end
```

Looks like "each" is the most efficient for this silly benchmark:

```
               user     system      total        real
reduce:    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.003384)
each:      0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.002549) # <-- winner!
set:       0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.012549)
```

Comment: My benchmark (posted as an answer), using an about 110.000 seized hash and an array seized 1000, shows your code as winner.

Answer (score 3):

Traversing the array:

```
a={"aa"=>[1, 2], "bbb"=>[3, 4, 5], "c"=>[6, 7, 8], "hh"=>[9]}
b=["aa","c"]
c = {}
b.each{|key| c[key] = a[key]}
#=>{"aa"=>[1, 2], "c"=>[6, 7, 8]}
```

Comment: This seems to be faster, but with 110.000 keys is expansive in memory, and if swap is needed will be slower

Comment: Actually the hash.select runs through all 110.000 keys; this searches only the required subset - and hashes are very efficient in searching.

Answer (score 2):

```
a={"aa"=>[1, 2], "bbb"=>[3, 4, 5], "c"=>[6, 7, 8], "hh"=>[9]}
b=["aa","c"]
h = b.each_with_object({}) { |i, h| h[i] = a[i] }
p h
# => {"aa"=>[1, 2], "c"=>[6, 7, 8]}
```

Another alternative:

```
Hash[b.zip(a.values_at(*b))]
# => {"aa"=>[1, 2], "c"=>[6, 7, 8]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Benchmarks!

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'set'
a = {}
("aaaa".."gggg").each{|k| a[k]=true}
p a.size #=>109675
b = a.keys.sample(1000) #try other numbers

b_set=b.to_set
c={}

Benchmark.bm(15) do |x|
  x.report("select"){a.select{|k,v| b.include? k}}
  x.report("set"){a.select{|k,v| b_set.include? k}}
  x.report("array.each"){b.each{|key| c[key] = a[key]}}
  x.report("array.inject"){b.reduce({}) { |memo,x| memo[x]=a[x]; memo }}
  x.report("assoc"){Hash[b.map{|i| a.assoc(i)}]}
  x.report("values_at"){Hash[b.zip(a.values_at(*b))]}
end
```

Output (on an ancient laptop):

```
                      user     system      total        real
select           22.860000   0.030000  22.890000 ( 24.454489)
set               0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.115898)
array.each        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001589)
array.inject      0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001265)
assoc            26.090000   0.060000  26.150000 ( 29.330769)
values_at         0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001455)
```

Comment: OMG! `#assoc` is taking too much time, according to your benchmark. I am surprised. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
b=["aa","c"]
a={"aa"=>[1, 2], "bbb"=>[3, 4, 5], "c"=>[6, 7, 8], "hh"=>[9]}
Hash[b.map{|i| a.assoc(i)}]
#=> {"aa"=>[1, 2], "c"=>[6, 7, 8]}
```